# SIGSEGV / Stack-Overflow when opening a TDBF

Tags: segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, lazarus, tdbf

After calling a new form and opening a DBF in this new form an SIGSEGV in Lazarus and a Stack-Overflow when running the program outside Lazarus appears.
The OS is Win 10.

Identical calling 2 other forms do not create this error.

### What can be the problem?

Calling from form TF_Menu:

---

```
procedure TF_Menu.Men_ModulesClick(Sender: TObject);

begin
  MModulNr := Module.Fields.FieldByName('NR').Value;
  Module.close;

  F_Menu.Visible := false;      // Called form unvisible
  F_Modules := TF_Modules.Create(Nil);  // New form being created
  F_Modules.ShowModal;       // New form being activated/shown
  FreeAndNil(F_Modules);     // New form destroyed
  F_Menu.Visible := true;
// …
end;
```

---

New form TF_Modules with the error at Module.Open:

---

```
procedure TF_Modules.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin
  Module.FilePathFull := Modules_Lw;
  Module.ReadOnly := false;
  Module.Open;                // Here the error occurs
  Module.IndexName := 'NR';
end;
```

---

Comment: That's interesting:

Do I use a different DBF in the TDBF: It is working
Do I use a different DBF in the TDBF: Not working
Do I rename the dbf in question: Not working
Do I put the DBF into a different folder and rename it: Not working

Answer (score 1):

It was not a defect dbf. I have created the dbf completely new and all the same.

Have now cretated the form completely new and up to now everything is running just fine. God knows what that was.